# Add affiliate tracking code to Open Cart?

Tags: php, opencart

I've recently registered my site at an affiliate network which lets blogs write about me for a fixed price. But I'm having some difficulties adding the code properly.

Here's the code that I'm supposed to add:
`<iframe src="http://track.domain.com/?trackID=[CookieID]&orderValue=[orderValue]&orderID=[orderID]&programID=319" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>`

So here's the code I tried to add in the success-page, which is where the code is supposed to be sent to the affiliate network (if the page is accessed through a given link). Notice that I'm trying to send a test order just to make sure it's added to my profile.

```
<?php 
class ControllerCheckoutSuccess extends Controller { 
public function index() { 

        $adrecordPixel = '<iframe src="http://track.adrecord.com/?trackID=' . $_COOKIE['trackID'] . '&orderValue=555555&orderID=5555555&programID=319&test=' . $this->session->data['order_id'] . '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>';
```

And

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->data['text_message'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_customer'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/order', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/download', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('information/contact'));

        $this->data['text_message'] = $adrecordPixel;
```

But it doesn't work :(

Anyone has any idea on how I can do this?

I will refresh each 5 minutes to check for answers and I will reply asap. If anyone wants to know the URL just ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you view the page source, do you see the tracking iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing over $text_message variable with this line:

```
$this->data['text_message'] = $adrecordPixel;
```

Just prepare the html in its own variable in the controller index() function and pass it:

```
$this->data['pixel'] = '<iframe src="http://track.adrecord.com/?trackID=' . $_COOKIE['trackID'] . '&orderValue=555555&orderID=5555555&programID=319&test=' . $this->session->data['order_id'] . '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>';
```

Then echo $pixel in your view wherever.